# VS 2010 and MBUnit how to run just one test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mbunit

I have Gallio/MbUnit installed and am using VS 2010 RC and I want to be able to run a single unit test or just all unit tests inside of a TestFixture and not all the tests in the entire project everytime I debug.  How do you do this in VS 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see it earlier but VS 2010 has a Test List Editor which allows me to add the specific test to a a list and run it from there so that only the one test is run.  I know that TD.Net probably has a right click/run test option for a test method but I didn't want to buy it and install yet another tool.

Comment: The Test List Editor is the only way without installing yet another Dev Tool.  However I now believe that it is a bug that all tests run in VS 2010 when you "Run Tests in Current Context"

Answer (score 5):

Install testdriven.net, there is a free personal version

http://www.testdriven.net/

Answer (score 3):

- As Simon said, [TD.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) is just working well.
- If you work with VS2010 Premium or Ultimate, you may also use the built-in test run feature of VS2010. It should find and run your MbUnit tests as well (if the [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org) add-in was installed)
- You may also run your tests by using [Resharper 5](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/beta/beta.html), but it seems that the latest beta of Resharper 5 has broken the Gallio test driver. It should be fixed soon however.

Apart from the VS2010 IDE, you may also run your tests with **Echo** (a powerful console application located in the bin folder of the Gallio installation directory), **Icarus** (Winform application with a nice UI; same location), or from PowerShell (by using the [Run-Gallio snap-in](http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/2008/09/gallio-powershell.html)). You can also invoke the test runner from one of the numerous extensions of Gallio for MSBuild, NAnt, TeamCity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, how we do it is select the specification inside visual studio, press F5, and it runs the specification via a Rake task.

Example:

```
class DiffuserObserverSpecification 
      : AutoMockSpecification<DiffuserObserver, IDiffuserObserver>

class When_diffuser_observer_is_created : DiffuserObserverSpecification

class When_diffuser_observer_has_injected_diffuser_change 
      : DiffuserObserverSpecification
```

So to execute the behaviour expectations of all DiffuserObserverSpecification, we select the DiffuserObserverSpecification and press F5.

And to execute just the behaviour for When_diffuser_observer_is_created, select that and press F5.

After one month you forget what I debugger looks like.