# Can not run MBUnit unit tests, there is no run button/menu

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mbunit, gallio

I have installed MBUnit and Gallio via nuget package, but there is no context menu or button where I can say run tests etc...

Do I still have to install something?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS 2010 and MBUnit how to run just one test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254167/vs-2010-and-mbunit-how-to-run-just-one-test)

Answer (score 0):

I use [TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/) for running MbUnit test within visual studio(2013 ultimate) , and Gallio Icarus GUI tool for running them externally . I presume you could do the same

Answer (score 0):

I installed on my VS2010 now NUnit nuget package and the free Visual NUnit extension for VS2010.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8164c71-0836-4471-80ce-633383031099

I can not use Testdriven.NET personal licence in a commercial area!